# Rearrange category page in order: cat image, title, description and then products

Tags: magento2, category, category-view

I'm using Magetique template for Magento and I'm changing the 'listing-layout-1.xml' file.

I need it to look like this [image]

Although, right now it's looking like this:
[image]

And the title isn't even displaying.

Here's my code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="category.image" />
        <move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" after="page.main.title" before="category.products.list" />
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list_layout_1.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list_layout_1.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Changes below :**

```
 <move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="category.image" />
        <move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" after="page.main.title" before="category.products.list" />
```

**to**

```
<move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" before="page.main.title"  />
<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="category.products.list"/> />
```

Comment: This doesn't work pleas see here: https://imgur.com/a/l1OjU

Comment: The description has moved below image, which is good, but it's not within the container and the title hasn't displayed.

Comment: can u please tell me category.products.list page container name?Also remove  `destination="columns.top"` and see what happen?

Comment: Where would I find this?

Comment: it too complex  to tell what is reference container name of `category.products.list `

Comment: Still wouldn't know where to find this.